# Is there any way ,I will set database at the top of xquery file without passing it to spawn/eval/invoke

Tags: database, eval, marklogic, invoke, spawn

Is there any way ,I will set database at the top of xquery file without passing it to spawn/eval/invoke function
example -

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
set database to "db1"
xdmp:invoke-function($func) (: here we won't pass the database as it been set at the top :)
```

Comment: I don't think so.  You could just declare a variable with the DBname at the top of the file and use it in the invoke/spawn.

Comment: Run your code on an app server that is linked to the right database. Eval/spawn/invoke into other database requires special privs, although you could use Amps to provide that priv inside a shielded (custom) function..

Comment: Do you want to invoke against a database other than the one associated with the appserver, and just don't like specifying it in the options every time?

Comment: You have asked multiple questions that have answers and none have been marked as accepted. When you receive an acceptable answer to your questions, you should click the checkbox to mark them as answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Actually ,I am calling a rest service extension through put method ,and there in the service extension, right know I am passing  the database name(where I want some update operation) in the options  of spawn function .that I want to avoid.